# MS ACCESS Adding Calculated fields

Tags: ms-access

I am having a problem trying to add two calculated fields in Access. I have a table with two calculated fields A and B and I want to create a new calculated field C that will add both fields A and B. I have tried adding them together but it is not working.However, when I try multiplying the two fields A and B the results is correct but when adding it gives wrong results.

Comment: Could you post the SQL you are using for this query - go into the query design view and select SQL View on the 'View' button (next to the 'Run' button).

Answer (score 1):

Don't use these calculated fields. They will get you anything but trouble - as you see now.

Instead, create a query with the table as source, and add the calculations you need as expressions. Use the query builder wizard and GUI.